# Time series data for probability of default (or credit ratings)

Tags: time-series, credit-risk, default-probability, database, credit-ratings

I'm currently investigating potential correlations among ESG ratings and credit ratings; more in particular, i'm trying to understand whether such correlation evolved during the last 20 (?) years, and to which degree ESG ratings can be considered an explanatory variable for credit ratings and probability of default.
For my empirical analysis I am employing ESG data and fundamentals of 900+ companies in Europe, obtained from the Refinitiv/Eikon Datastream database; however, the crucial time series for my analysis would be the time series of probabilities of default for the above-mentioned companies. The problem is, such time series is not available in the database: i can only retrieve the current observation. 
So, my question is: does anybody know where I can find time series data for European equities regarding default probability, or equivalently distance-to-default, credit rating, ...?  
As an alternative, could you suggest some other financial variable in which the PD is required as an input and for which the time series is instead available, so that i can retrieve the necessary data by inverting the equation? 
Thanks to everybody willing to help. Any suggestion is largely appreciated.

Comment: i don't know. However I have one suggestion. Instead of probabilities of default, you might have easier time finding credit spreads on companies' debt trading in secondary markets; or CDS spreads for the relatively few companies that have liquid CDS. This spread includes the view on both PD andrecovery, but for our correlations it should not matter. As for historical agency ratings, I'm skeptical that they'd be very informative, but you can probably pay Moody's and S&P to get them.

Comment: thanks for your reply; regarding CDS, i already checked on the database but there's no homogeneity in the tenor of the product, plus they're not available for the majority of my equities. Regarding credit spread in secondary markets, that might be interesting (still, assuming that i'm able to get the recovery rate data as well). You have any idea where i could look up such data, and under what name that would be published? just "credit spread"? Sorry if I'm asing obvious questions but i'm not really used to data research and collection.

Comment: what do you mean by "no homogeneity in the tenor of the product"? For names that have CDS quoted, 5 years is by far the most liquid, and other tenors are much less liquid and not often quoted. <BR> Finding recovery rate is as hard as finding PD - it's not observable... but look into https://www.moodys.com/Pages/Default-and-Recovery-Analytics.aspx .

Comment: I only looked it quickly because my time on the Refinitiv / Eikon platform was running out, but it seemed to me at a first glance that the CDS were quoted for mainly 5 years, but for some entities also 1, 4, 10 and i honestly didn't know how to justify a single choice. Anyway, thank you very much, you've given me many cues i'll try to look into. Hopefully through either moody's or CDSs i'll be able to retrieve the data i need. \ Thanks again.